# Prove $1+2+3+...+n<=n^2$ for all n∈N

Tags: proof-writing, induction

> Prove $1+2+3+...+n<=n^2$ for all n∈N

This is what I have so far. Not sure what to do now.[image]

Comment: Another way to show this (for fun) is using $$1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n^2+n}{2}\leq\frac{n^2+n^2}{2}$$for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @Dave: RHS probably should be $n^2$?

Comment: Well $$\frac{n^2+n^2}{2}=\frac{2n^2}{2}=n^2$$

Comment: $1+2+3+\cdots+n < n+n+n+\cdots + n = n^2$. That can work inductively.

Comment: Surely a user of your reputation knows the command `\le` $\le$

Comment: @Dave: Yeah, I just read too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use the inductive hypothesis to show it suffices to prove
$$n^2+n+1<(n+1)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

One potential stumbling block is that your "in other words" isn't quite complete.  What "$P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$" really says is that *if*

$$
1+2+\cdots+k \leq k^2
$$

*then*

$$
1+2+\cdots+k+(k+1) \leq (k+1)^2
$$

In other words (!), you use the premise that $1+2+\cdots+k \leq k^2$ as the starting point.  If you add $k+1$ to both sides, you get

$$
1+2+\cdots+k+(k+1) \leq k^2+(k+1)
$$

Can you finish the line of reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Gauss’s sum formula : $$1+2+\dots +n=\frac  {n(n+1)}2$$
For $n\ge1$, we have $\frac{n (n+1)}2\le\frac  {n (n+n)}2=n^2$...

Thus we have a proof without induction,  in case you are interested. ..

Comment: That looks so much easier. But I'm pretty sure we learn that later on in the chapter, so I assume I am not allowed to use it on this assignment

Comment: @CraigD ok...  incidentally,  gauss figured this out in grade school. ..

Comment: guess i'm no gauss :)

Comment: @CraigD few are